# MomentJS - displaying now/ tomorrow instead of today/ tomorrow's date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using a component from [AntUI](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/) library that renders the date picker.

What I want to do is to display `Now` and `Tomorrow` instead of today's/ tomorrow's dates.

Is there a specific momentJS format (I couldn't find any, so probably not) or a way to configure momentJS library that it will automatically display those values instead of those dates?

Comment: Now and today are same if you are only using date

Comment: Do you mean you want to display the timestamp (date + time)?

Comment: So instead of `29.05.2018` as it is 29th May 2018, I would like to display `Today` or `Now`, and instead of `30.05.2018` I would like to display `Tomorrow`. It is extremely easy to do this on my own, but not when I only have access to the `format` prop in the mentioned library, or only to the `moment` object

Comment: [Calendar time from the MomentJS documentation.](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/)

Comment: @Pointy This is probably something that I can use, however not sure if the component I'm using will take this into account. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could check if the date is between `moment().startOf('day');` and `moment().endOf('day');` and display `Now` or `Tomorrow` depending on the result

```
moment().isBetween(moment().startOf('day'), moment().endOf('day'));
```

would be `Now` (true) and

```
moment().add(1, 'day').isBetween(moment().startOf('day'), moment().endOf('day'));
```

and this would be `Tomorrow` (false)

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately I do not have this amount of power when using the component.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var today = moment().endOf('day')
    var tomorrow = moment().add(1, 'day').endOf('day')
    var date = new Date();
    //Check Today's date 
    if (date < today) 
      alert('today')
    if (date < tomorrow) 
      alert('tomorrow')
```

**UPDATE**

You can use this as well but it will show current time as well:

```
moment().calendar();                      // Today at 10:37 AM
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();       // Tomorrow at 10:37 AM
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but unfortunately I do not have this amount of power when using the component.

Comment: Could you please share more details, like how your controls look like and your expected output? So we may have better idea.